# Looking for render event in delegateEvents in Backbone.View

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, marionette, backbone-views

I have one question about `Backbone.View` and its `delegateEvents`. You can read in docs [here](http://backbonejs.org/#View-extend) about `extend` method. Using this method, you can *"override the render function, specify your declarative events"* etc.

I have a question about **declarative events** or **delegateEvents** (not sure how should I call it). They are described [here](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents). And here is an example:

```
  var DocumentView = Backbone.View.extend({
  events: {
    "dblclick"                : "open",
    "click .icon.doc"         : "select",
    "contextmenu .icon.doc"   : "showMenu",
    "click .show_notes"       : "toggleNotes",
    "click .title .lock"      : "editAccessLevel",
    "mouseover .title .date"  : "showTooltip"
  },    
  open: function() {
    window.open(this.model.get("viewer_url"));
  },
  select: function() {
    this.model.set({selected: true});
  }, 
  ...
});
```

As you can see, you can add different events on specific objects in template DOM. Like `click` or `mouseover`. So, having this template:

```
<foo></foo>
{#myplayers}
<player class="normal" value="{player}" style="{style}"></player>
{/myplayers}
```

You can add different `click` event on every single player, like this:

```
    events: {
        'click player': 'playerClick'
    },
    playerClick: function( e ) {
        var playerValue = e.currentTarget.getAttribute( 'value' );
        // HERE: e.currentTarget I've particular player

    }
```

**My question: Can I declare render event in similar way as click event?** I want to catch event when single player (not the whole list) is rendered. I need to get `e.currentTarget` there and change its css a little bit.

I'm looking for something like this:

```
events: {
    'render player': 'playerRendered'
},
playerRendered: function( e ) {
    var playerValue = e.currentTarget.getAttribute( 'value' );
    // HERE: e.currentTarget I've particular player

}
```

How can I do this? Because `render` in delegateEvents, doesn't work:/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe in the initialize function within your view you can have a listenTo with the render. Something like that:

```
var view = Backbone.View.extend({
    className: 'list-container',
    template: _.template($('#my-template').html()),
    initialize: function () {
      this.listenTo(this, 'render', function () {
        console.info('actions');          
      });
    },
    render: function() {
      this.$el.html(this.template(this));
      return this;
    },
});
```

And then:

```
var myView = new view();
myView.render();
myView.trigger('render');
$('#container').html(myView.el);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({     
  events: {
    'render .myselector': 'playerRendered'
},
playerRendered: function( e ) {
    console.log("arguments");
    var playerValue = e.currentTarget.getAttribute( 'value' );
    // HERE: e.currentTarget I've particular player

},
render:function(){

  console.log("render");
 this.$el.html("<div class='myselector'></div>");
}
});
var view = new View();
view.render();
```

and you can trigger with [Jquery trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

```
   this.$(".myselector").trigger("render");
```

or outside your view

```
  view.$(".myselector").trigger("render");
```